# word 2010 - style to make a grey area around my text

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to make a style to get a grey background behind a paragraph and to have this background extended a little bit before and after my text.

So I created a style and applied a grey shading. The result is nearly OK but I would like the grey area to extend 10 pts above and 10 pts below, how do I do that? if I play with the "line spacing" parameter, the grey box extends below but **not before** my text.

The only way I have found so far to mimic the effect I want is to insert a paragraph before and after the text to extend the grey area but i don't like this solution.

EDIT: and following a suggestion below, I'd rather not have to draw something with the mouse each time I want to grey one paragraph or another. Ideally, I would select the paragraph with the mouse in the fuzzy way allowed by styles and just hit a key mapped to the appropriate function.

[image]

Comment: You can also put spacing before a paragraph ...

Comment: this is exactly what i would like to be able to do but changing the before and after number of points do not modify the size of the grey zone, the grey zone changes only if you change the "line spacing" and set it for instance to "double" and in that case you end up with the "with added spacing" line from the picture above i.e. the grey zone is extended after but not before the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i have found a solution that works for me. Here it is:

- select a paragraph
- in the quick style sub-menu select "**save selection as new quick
  style**"
- enter a name for the new style e.g. "greyed"
- click **modify**
- click **format / border / box** and click **options** (at the bottom right)
- choose the **top** and **bottom** values that suits you (e.g. 10 pt) and hit OK
- if you don't want to see the border make its color = to white!
- now select the **Shading tab**
- choose a color in the **Fill** menu (a nice light gray in my case :) )
- OK out of the style edit and enjoy!!!

There is a caveat though, this thing will not work nicely with bullets but for my use it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for effect something like this,

[image]

**Enter :-   The textbox**

Textbox is made specially for this. It also has various formating options. to insert it find it under "insert shapes"

---

I tried adjusting paragraph spacing settings and the result is below; the areas marked with black arrows remain non-shaded.

So conclusion is using text box is better way to do that. Text box are made for that background shade in the first place. Text box allows you to give dimension to the box precisely so the shaded area is exactly how much is needed .One important other feature is the "text warp" feature of text box but that entirely different topic.
[image]

Comment: it works but it is a lot of clicks and mouse, i would even have to draw the box! that is why i am looking to something style-like, can i make it a one click standard shape?! i am unsure it can ever work because the dimensions of the shape won"t ever take into account the number of lines i have already typed

Comment: You need to type **within** the box.   you you need to copy paste that is already typed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is in the paragraph properties. When modifying the Style, use the <kbd>Format</kbd> button to select `Paragraph`, then adjust line spacing to have spacing `BEFORE` the line.

[image]

Comment: on my PC, this does NOT extend the grey area, it just adds white spacing, does it work on your machine?

Comment: My apologies. Yesterday, I did something that created what you were looking for and thought this was it. I can't reproduce it now. :-(

Comment: np, cool animation btw, which soft did you use?

Comment: I used LICEcap to record it.

Comment: for your information, i have found a solution that works. Please see answer above. Maybe that is what you were thinking about.